# Proving that there is a unique linear map such that $T(u_i)=v_i$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I have a problem with understanding of a rather simple concept in linear algebra. I have seen in a book, a following question:

> Suppose $U,V$ are vector spaces over $K$ and $u_1,\dots,u_n$ is a basis of $U$. Let $v_1,\dots, v_n$ be any sequence of $n$ vectors in $V$. Prove that there is a unique map $T:U\rightarrow V$ with $T(u_i)=v_i$, for $1\leq i \leq n$.

The proof given in this book is:

> Let $u \in U$. Then since $u_1,\dots, u_n$ is a basis of $U$, there exists uniquely determined $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in K$ with $u=\alpha_1 u_1+\dots+\alpha_n u_n$. So that, if $T$ exists, then we must have:
>   $$T(u)=T(\alpha_1 u_1+\dots+\alpha_n u_n)=\alpha_1 v_1+\dots+\alpha_n v_n$$
>   and so $T$ is uniquely determined.

Honestly this proof makes little sense to me. How does it prove uniqueness? Is this proof complete? Could someone explain this to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Repeat the argument for 'another' map, say $T'$. You get $T(u)=T'(u)$, for all $u\in U$. **Edit:** An analyst would say that the RHS, $\alpha_1 v_1+\dots+\alpha_n v_n$, does not depend on $T$, so all such maps will do the same, hence uniqueness.

Comment: It is just linearity; if you asked about another T you have to define it otherwise

Comment: I still don't really get this. If a take another map, why the RHS does not change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say we have another mapping $f:U \to V$ such that $f(u_i)=v_i, \forall i$. Then, for each $u \in U:$  $T(u)=T(a_1u_1+\dots + a_nu_n)=a_1T(u_i)+\dots + a_nT(u_n)=a_1v_1+ \dots a_nv_n=a_1f(u_1)+ \dots + a_nf(u_n)$
$=f(a_1u_1+ \dots +a_nu_n)=f(u)$
 Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You like for the map $T$ to be a function of $u$ and $v_1,v_2,\cdots, v_n$. You can do so by making a slight change of notation $u = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iu_i = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n)$, and $A = \begin{pmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\...\\v_n\end{pmatrix}$, then define $T:U \to V: T(u) = u\cdot A$, then you check that $T(u_i) = (0,0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0)\cdot \begin{pmatrix} v_1\\ v_2\\...\\v_i\\...\\v_n\end{pmatrix}=v_i$. Proving uniqueness is simple for if there is another map $T': U \to V: T'(u_i)=v_i \to T'(u) = u\cdot A = T(u) \to T'=T$.

Comment: Does it matter that $v_i$ represents a basis. Could we have taken any random set of vectors?