# Do we need to prove $A^{-1}$ is linear for proving $A: V \mapsto W$ is an isomophism if $Av_k = w_k$ for $k=1,...,n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*, to prove the theorem

> Theorem 6.7. Let $A : V \mapsto W$ be a linear map,and let $v_1, v_2, . . . , v_n$
>   and $w_1, w_2, . . . , w_n$ be bases in $V$ and $W$ respectively. If $Avk = wk$,
>   $k = 1, 2, . . . , n$, then $A$ is an isomorphism.

we only needs to define $A^{-1}$ by $A^{−1}w_k = v_k, k = 1,2, . . . , n$.

But I am thinking do we need to also show that $A^{-1}$ is linear? If so, how to show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with bases here, there is one and only one *linear* map $B\colon W\longrightarrow V$ such that$$(\forall k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):Bw_k=v_k.$$Then it is trivial that$$(\forall k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):(AB)w_k=w_k\text{ and that }(\forall k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):(BA)v_k=v_k.$$Therefore, $B=A^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand the first line. Why there is one and only one linear map? I still cannot see how the map is linear. Do we need to show that?

Comment: I am using here the theorem that says that if we have a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $V$ and if we have $n$ vectors $w_1,\ldots,w_n\in W$, then there is one and only one linear map $f\colon V\longrightarrow W$ such that $f(v_k)=w_k$ for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: so, it is related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277726/proving-that-there-is-a-unique-linear-map-such-that-tu-i-v-i)

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}$

Answer (score 0):

I. $A$ is 1-1.

If $Au=0$, where $u=c_1v_1+\cdots c_nv_n$, then 
$$0=Au=c_1Av_1+\cdots c_nAv_n=c_1w_1+\cdots+c_nw_n$$
and as the $w_k$'s are linearly independent, then $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$, and hence $u=0$.

II. $A$ is onto.

Let $w\in W$. Then as $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a basis of $W$, there exist $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, such that
$$
w=c_1w_1+\cdots+c_nw_n=c_1Av_1+\cdots+c_nAv_n=A(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n),
$$
and thus $A$ is onto.

Comment: So, you are showing that A is one-on-one and onto. And that means invertibility. Am I correct?

Comment: I am trying to define a map by $^{−1}_=_$ in order to show that A is an isomorphism. But I not sure whether I need to show $A^{-1}$ is linear.