# The relation between matrices and linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

- Context

I've been learning about linear maps and matrices while I'm a little confused about some of the details. To make my description of the problem clear, I'll set the general case: a linear map $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, where $V$ and $W$ are two finite dimensional vector spaces, $\mathcal{M}(T)$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases: $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ of $V$ and $w_1,w_2,...,w_m$ of $W$.

- Confusion

I'm clear that the linear map $\mathcal{M}$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\mathbf{F}^{m,n}$, so for every linear map we can get its matrix with respect to two bases. However, what about the inverse case, how can I determine the linear map behind a specific matrix $A$?  Maybe let $T$ be the map from $V$ to $W$ such that $Tv_k=\sum_{j=1}^mA_{j,k}w_j$ ?

If that's right, since we also know that each m-by-n matrix $A$ induces a linear map from $\mathbf{F}^{n,1}$ to $\mathbf{F}^{m,1}$, namely T that takes $x\in\mathbf{F}^{n,1}$ to $Ax\in\mathbf{F}^{m,1}$, now, is this $A$ the matrix of this $T$? If this is true, then it is much simpler to determine the linear map behind a matrix.

- Why I want to know this?

Since I often encounter problems with matrices, and I am thinking of convert them into the problems of linear maps (or operators), is that a way to easily turn the matrix into the linear map behind it so that I can deal with the certain linear map ?

Comment: The notation needs to indicate the bases $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal W$ as well. Maybe $\mathcal M(T;\mathcal V,\mathcal W)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right, the formal notation should be $\mathcal{M}(T,(v_1,v_2,...,v_n),(w_1,w_2,...,w_m))$, but since the bases are clear from the context I just use the simpler notation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to know the bases of a particular matrix with only the knowledge of the entries in that matrix. However, if you know the bases of that matrix then the corresponding linear map can be written

$T(v)=T(\alpha_1 v_1+\dots+\alpha_n v_n)=\alpha_1T(v_1)+\dots+\alpha_nT(v_n)=\alpha_1(A_{1,1}w_1+\dots+A_{m,1}w_m)+\dots+\alpha_n(A_{1,n}w_1+\dots+A_{m,n}w_m)$

So your idea is correct. It may be helpful to consider the below theorem if you haven't already done so.
[Proving that there is a unique linear map such that $T(u_i)=v_i$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277726/proving-that-there-is-a-unique-linear-map-such-that-tu-i-v-i)

Comment: Thank you. So in this manner, if, as I said in my second paragraph, let $T: x \to Ax$ then $A$ is actually the matrix of this $T$, under the standard bases of the two spaces ($\mathbf{F}^{n,1}$ and $\mathbf{F}^{m,1}$), right?

Comment: @Smaug Yes, in this case $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$, but it doesn't have to be with respect to the standard bases. If the bases of the matrix representation of $T$ change, then the entries in that matrix may also change. The entries of $x$ and $Ax$ may also change, because they are matrices of vectors defined $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ such that $v=a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_n v_n$ for some basis $(v_1 , \dots , v_n$). Note that matrices of vectors are distinct from vectors, although the matrix of a vector with respect to the standard basis will have the same entries as that vector.

Comment: @Smaug Naturally, regarding the equation in the answer, $(v_1 , \dots , v_n)$ and $(w_1 , \dots , w_m)$ are the bases of the matrix $A$ in the equation. The theorem in the link may be needed to understand this topic. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @Smaug Also, please kindly mark my answer as accepted if this answers your question, and vote it useful or not useful.